# Java HTTP request invalid method?

Tags: java, http

I am trying to use java to create HTTP requests, but I am getting an invalid method and I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
String str = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + this.url + "\r\n";
int i=r.nextInt(agents.length);
String uAgent = agents[i]; //agents is an array of user agents.
  str = str + "User-Agent: "+uAgent+"\r\n";
  str = str + "Content-Length: " + (int)(Math.random() * 1000.0D) + "\r\n"; //random content length for now
  str = str + "X-a: " + (int)(Math.random() * 1000.0D) + "\r\n"; //random

 HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(this.url).openConnection();
 con.setRequestMethod(str);
 con.setConnectTimeout(5000); //set timeout to 5 seconds
 con.connect();
 System.out.print(".");
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: http://example.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US)
Content-Length: 434
X-a: 660   
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:339)
    at jbot.HTTP.run(HTTP.java:88)
```

It seems like I am using a valid method, so I don't know.

Comment: request method is only one word GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|PUT|DELETE|TRACE|CONNECT. Your `str` is the complete request header, rather than "method".

Comment: *"It seems like I am using a valid method, so I dont know."* - It seems like you didn't bother to read the javadoc.  Hint, hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An HTTP request method is just one word:  "GET", "POST", etc.  The other lines are request headers which you can set using `setRequestProperty`.  For example:

```
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", uAgent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, step back and check out the docs for [`HttpUrlConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod%28java.lang.String%29):

`HttpUrlConnection` is an abstraction on TOP of HTTP. It helps you out so you don't have to manually write HTTP strings, such as you have done.

`setRequestMethod` requires a simple `String` and tells you EXACTLY what it allows. You don't need to do the entire HTTP line manually if you use `HttpUrlConnection` (in fact, GET is the default, just don't set the method for a GET).

You can set "properties" as they are called for `HttpUrlConnection` with [`setRequestProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

That's what you would use to set the headers, with simple key-value pairs (and user-agent is a header). For params, since you're using a GET, they would be part of the URL (querystring).

If you want to send a string to an HTTP server manually, like you've constructed (you probably don't want to, but just in case), you just need to connect to it with a `Socket` and fire away (don't use a helper library such as `HttpUrlConnection`).

Comment: How would I set the useragent along with those other params then?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a reference to setRequestProperty, which you can use for headers./

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod(java.lang.String)) the `setRequestMethod` only expects the method i.e. "GET", "POST", "PUT" etc.

you want something like this:

```
URL serverAddress = new URL("http://localhost");
//set up out communications stuff
HttpURLConnection connection = null;

//Set up the initial connection
connection = (HttpURLConnection)serverAddress.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

connection.connect();
```

Comment: How would I set the useragent along with those other params then?

Comment: `connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", uAgent);`

Answer (score 0):

"GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, TRACE", these are the valid arguments to pass the method bellow:

```
void setRequestMethod(String method)
```

To set the other property (like, User-Agent in your case) you can use the following method like bellow:

```
con.setRequestProperty("<Property-name>", <property-value>)
```

Thanks and happy coding!